# String building and concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need some help with string building and concatenation in JavaScript.

I have a form on a website where a user inputs a VIP name which is then added to the end of my URL to build a dynamic dashboard.

My code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {   
$('#open').click(function() {
    var fixedData1 = 'http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=',   
        userEntry1 = $('#one').val();
    var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + userEntry1);
    newWindow.focus();
});
});
```

Example. User enters.... app-123.network.dcs1.domain.com

which would then open a new page with the URL:

http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=app-123.network.dc.domain.com

This is great and works fine, however I want to make the 'DC' part a variable, I have two DC's dcS1/dcS2 at the moment a user would enter like the above and specify the dc in the name. This only opens a dashboard with that particular dc.

I want to be able to pass the VIP name with the dc as a variable, so

vip=app-123.network.$dc.domain.com

even if it is entered with a specific named dc by the user.

If this even possible? I don't know where to begin.

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear, but if I've understood correctly, you want to accept entries like this:

```
XXX.dcS1.YYY
XXX.dcS2.YYY
```

but pass through the following to your service:

```
XXX.$dc.YYY
```

You can use a regex to make the substitution:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {   
    $('#open').click(function() {
        var regex = /\.(dcS[12])\./;
        var fixedData1 = 'http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=',   
            userEntry1 = $('#one').val(),
            replaced = userEntry1.replace(regex, '.$dc.');

        var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + replaced);
        newWindow.focus();
    });
});
```

For the above, if the user entered `app-123.network.dcS1.domain.com` then they would be sent to `http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=app-123.network.$dc.domain.com`.

Test out the regex here:

https://regex101.com/r/mCcR0D/2

If I haven't understood correctly then let me know.

Comment: Mike you the man! Yes you understood my question perfectly and the above looks great, I am though both new too and scared of Regex's, my example was simplified, dcs1/dcs2, my DC's are actually called PAL/PFW, any chance of a hand with the regex for that and I think the rest is perfect, if a user then enters either PAL or PFW it will pass back through to my service as xxxxx.$dc.yyyyy :) me = happy man!

Comment: Not sure regex is necessarily the best tool for such a simple replacement, but `/\.(PAL|PFW)\./i` should do it. https://regex101.com/r/mCcR0D/4/

Answer (score 0):

ES2015's back ticks can let you use `${}` variable in strings:

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
  let s = $('#one').val().toUpperCase().trim(); // s1 >>> S1
  let url = `http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=app-123.network.dc${s}.domain.com`;
  let newWindow = window.open(url);
  newWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: But... `user enters the string` specifically the string that contains `dc` so he needs `string.replace()`

Comment: slebetman, any chance of an example with string replace? I can read all day and not get anywhere but one good example normally does the trick :)

Comment: `var url = "http://testwebsite/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip=app-123.network.dc"+s+".domain.com";
`

Comment: This is called TemplateLiteral, and it can also be tagged on the invokation (depending on how the function handles the arguments, though).